# How to make view go under navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios11

In iOS 11, when the navigation bar is shown (after having been hidden), the entire view below it moves down. How can I stop this from happening?

Nav bar hidden:

[image: hidden]

Nav bar showing:

[image: Nav bar showing]

Comment: Check this: https://imgur.com/a/buMVK

Comment: I've implemented a custom search control and when it is displayed, it hides the navigation bar, then, when the user disposes it, the navigation bar is shown back (I have also an animation to move the Navigation Bar out of the visible area). But I couldn't repeat your problem. Have you checked the Navigation Bar's safeAreaLayoutGuide when it is displayed ?

Comment: @RichieRich Didn't work

Comment: @Sergiob Is safeAreaLayoutGuide enabled by default? Mine seems to be disabled

Comment: It depends. You can enable it from Interface Builder. It's a new layout guide introduced starting from iOS 11. Before it was used the topLayoutGuide (and the bottomLayoutGuide) they were replaced by safeAreaLayoutGuide. Take a look at the meaning of the layout guides here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide. But the behaviour I see from your pictures is quite weird. Are sure you don't move any view ?

Answer (score 0):

set the transparency of navigation to false.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false;
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything to the view below it

Comment: it does. do it in viewWillAppear()